# Group structures on Hausdorff space

Tags: group-theory, big-list, topological-groups

Could anyone give me some practical (and possibly intuitive) examples of Group structures on Hausdorff spaces? Let us say you had to get freshmen university students interested into fields of maths they hardly ever heard of, and you would like to call their attention by drawing some everyday life examples (or sort of) which they could be fascinated by. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just looking for examples of Hausdorff groups or are you asking for a general method to endow a Hausdorff space with a group structure?

Comment: Do you assume the freshman knows what a Hausdorff space is or why are you asking about that specifically? (It sounds like there’s a freshman going “Hausdorff spaces? Meh. Groups? Boooring. Group structures on topological spaces? C’mon!” and then “Group structures on *Hausdorff spaces*? Say whaaaaaaat?”)

Comment: No, Let us say you start a class trying to call their attention by providing an intuitive and possibly graphic scenario, you make them reflect a bit on that, and you start to derive properties out of that, finally showing them that is what a group on a Hausdorff space looks like. That is the procedure I am thinking about.

Comment: Some examples would just suffice, I think, as far as they are intuitive.

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I think this wikipedia article is a good start however: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of standard examples for you. I've opted to make the examples as general as I can so that the list can be more mercifully short.

- $S^1=\{z\in\Bbb C : |z|=1\}$ group structure:  multiplication of complex numbers
- $F^*= F\setminus \{0\}$, $F$ a field. group structure:  multiplication of field elements
- $V$ any normed vector space. Group structure:  addition of vectors
- $\mathrm{GL}_n(V)$ and $\mathrm{SL}_n(V)$, a locally compact vector space. Group structure:  multiplication
- $G$ arbitrary with the discrete topology.
- Profinite groups with all groups in the system being given the discrete topology.
- $G/H$ where $G$ is any Hausdorff group and $H$ is a closed subgroup.

Note that the vector space example includes fields and the matrix rings over fields, similarly the arbitrary group with the discrete topology includes $\Bbb Z$, and subgroups are always winners, since subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are Hausdorff. In particular $\Bbb R^+$ follows from the $F^*$ example. I included the $S^1$ despite it being a subgroup of $\Bbb C^*$  because it's so central to the theory. Other notables include the Möbius tranforms on $\Bbb C$, which are related to projective special linear groups, themselves quotients of general linear groups by the closed subgroup of diagonal matrices.

Comment: Do all groups on Hausdorff spaces generate a co-group, thus becoming a Hopf algebra, or only a subset of them qualify?

Comment: @JavierArias Algebra structures require a ring structure beyond the group structure. There's not ever going to necessarily be a natural ring structure on a given group. Take $S^1$ for example, the natural choice for addition is complex number addition, under which $S^1$ is not closed.

Comment: Ok, so only a subset of them qualifies.